# I am running into this error: Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am a beginner, trying to learn flutter.
I am trying to run a flutter project but run into this error. Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1

I started with Android studio and I had the error, I then switched to VScode but I still get the same error even there also.
Anyone has an idea what I can do? Here are the screen shots.

[image: Error in Android studio]

[image: Error in VScode]

[image: And this is the flutter doctor result]

Comment: No screenshots of text please.  Paste the text enclosed with ``` on a line by itself both before and after the text.

Comment: Please make sure, you accept the SDK Licenses and have all the required plugins installed and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to accept Android licenses.
Try `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept.